# Using jQuery to insert <div>s after the adjacent <div>s

Tags: jquery, insertafter

Let's say I have a set of simple HTML elements as follows:

```
<div class="metadata">I'm metadata #1</div>
<div class="content">Hello, world!</div>

<p />

<div class="metadata">I'm metadata #2</div>
<div class="content">Hello, world!</div>
```

My aim is to insert each `div.metadata` immediately after the **adjacent** `div.content`. Obviously, I can try: `$("div.metadata").insertAfter("div.content");` but doing so (as expected) appends BOTH `div.metadata` elements to each `div.content` as shown in **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LspH6/1/)**.

You might think that assigning a unique ID to each **div** would make things simple, but 1) these tags are dynamically generated by a CMS and I'd like to avoid manually assigning IDs, and 2) there could be dozens of the same element pairs.

So, the question is, what's the most efficient way to insert after or append each `div.metadata` to the adjacent `div.content`?

Comment: So you want to 'relocate' the .metadata divs from 'before' to 'after' the .metadata's .content sibling?

Comment: In general, check out the [Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) section of jQuery's API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.content').after(function() {
    return $(this).prev('.metadata');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LspH6/3/)

Comment: Simple. Elegant. Right on the spot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.content').each(function(i) {
    $(this).prev('.metadata').insertAfter($(this));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jwhitfieldseed/h7VZd/

Comment: Is there a mismatch? Hmmm... :|

Comment: There was, I forgot to update the fiddle! sorted now.